# How much faith should I put in Unified Write Filter?

Tags: windows-8, embedded, uwf

I have a requirement to create a windows build which is ultra reliable. It's possible there will be frequent power loss on the PCs which I need to try and ensure this doesn't have a negative effect on the OS.

I'll be using Windows 8.1 Embedded IND Pro because of its lock down features. I plan to enable the [Unified Write Filter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn449332(v=winembedded.82).aspx) with 2 file and registry exceptions which are application specific. My expectation is that with UWF enabled, sudden power loss will not cause the OS / file system to enter an unusable state.

Having not used it before, I don't have field experience if UWF. Is my assumption correct? Are there pitfalls or other considerations here?

Hardware:

Intel NUC 6i5SYK

120GB M.2 SDD

4GB DDR4 SO-DIM

Comment: Apparently UWF is like the overlay system that live linuces use to run in RAM, So you want your windows to run virtually in RAM, and if/when a power failure (or just a reboot) happens, all filesystem changes will be lost (unless written to a non-overlay mount) but it'll always boot up clean? So nothing can change/corrupt/infect the main OS? Or are your goals different?

Comment: @Xen2050 Essentially I want the OS / file system to become incorruptible on power loss, booting up exactly the same each time. Using the RAM overlay for HHD writes is just fine for our purposes. I would add one directory and one registry key to the exceptions list. This application is not part of the OS. Its one we develop. .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're using the predecessor `EWF` at Win7 embedded machines since some years now without problems. Currently we are switching to Win10 and UWF, so I don't have long term experience yet, but afaik internally it is the same logic in EWF and UWF so I expect no problems, too. However, one thing I have heard is that the use of exclusions can cause problems. Also you have to carefully set and monitor the (used) overlay size to avoid write blockings.